# react to print not printing background color

Tags: reactjs, react-to-print

Hi I am using a library [react-to-print](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-to-print?source=post_page-----f469cc99b24a--------------------------------) to print my react component into a pdf form.

here is the code below

```
export default function Index() {

  const handlePrint = useReactToPrint({
    content: () => componentRef.current,
    copyStyles: true,
    pageStyle: print,
  });
     

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={handlePrint}>print</button>
      <div ref={componentRef}>
        <Header
          title="Seguro de Carro - Comparar Resultados"         
        />
      
        <HomeComparePackage packages={comparePack} />
        <HomeCompareMobile packages={comparePack} />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

The issue is it was printing footer in my pdf too, so what i did was add the configuration for it

```
  const print = `
  @media print {
    footer {
      display: none;
    }

  }
`;

 const handlePrint = useReactToPrint({
    content: () => componentRef.current,
    copyStyles: true,
    pageStyle: print,
  });
```

As soon as i changed the configuration to the above one, it started ignoring my css colors in the component? Is there a way i could preserve my css colors while setting footer to display null ?

Comment: try `@media print {
  @page { margin: 0; }
}`

Comment: @Liap thanks for the response but this now doesnt prints my css colors, and the images rendered in my component :(

Comment: have you try to refresh the page

Comment: @Liap yes but if i touch the print function it is ignoring my background colors, images and text colors, if i use default print function without touching it then it prints all the colors (just the footer too which i dont want)

Comment: checkout my answer. Hope it help you find sasuke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `body { -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; }`

```js
const handlePrint = useReactToPrint({
    content: () => componentRef.current,
    copyStyles: true,
    pageStyle: `
      @media print {
        @page { margin: 0; }
      }
      body {
        -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
      }
    `,
  });
```

In the default printer, you can see the `background graphics` checkbox

[image]

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/useref-t7wkwn?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt2rlw5u00063j6l1v99x48r%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt2rlw5t00023j6lyyvb4vkx%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt2rlw5u00033j6lpbo78v4j%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt2rlw5u00053j6l1753yvo3%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clt2rlw5t00023j6lyyvb4vkx%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt2rlw5t00023j6lyyvb4vkx%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%257D%252C%2522clt2rlw5u00053j6l1753yvo3%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt2rlw5u00043j6l6mirwgbv%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt2rlw5u00053j6l1753yvo3%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clt2rlw5u00043j6l6mirwgbv%2522%257D%252C%2522clt2rlw5u00033j6lpbo78v4j%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt2rlw5u00033j6lpbo78v4j%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)